# How to make transparent bottom sheet like google assistant

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, google-assistant

Basically, I am very impressed by google assistant UI/UX
to want to create a similar look and feel for my app.
but IDK how to approach this type of design. my app architecture is MVVM, Kotlin
so the functionality I want is when my app is opened I want it to create a custom button sheet with a few buttons and text.

the motive behind this style is users can access basic information without opening the app
for more complex interaction I would give a button to go fullscreen

I have attached an image below
[image]